# Problem with C# Proxy in test console script

Tags: c#, http, proxy, web-crawler, http-proxy

I have a project that has to get 100's of pages of data from a site each day. I use a paid for proxy with login details and I wait 5 seconds between requests so I don't hammer their site and pass a referer, user-agent and it is a simple GET request.

However I tried to make just a little C# Console script to test various ways of adding proxies e.g with or without credentials and got a working IP:Port from the web > http://www.freeproxylists.net/ to test it with, as my own details in this test didn't work. I am at a loss to why this test script isn't working when my main project is.

I am accessing an old site I own anyway so I am not blocking my own home IP as I can access it on the web (or any other page or site) in a browser easily.

Without using a proxy I just get a 30 second wait (the timeout length) then a "Timeout Error", with the proxy I get NO wait at all (free proxy OR one I own with credentials) before a "Timeout Error" - so whether I use a proxy or not it fails to return a response.

I am probably just sleep drained but would like to know what I am doing wrong as I just copied my "MakeHTTPGetRequest" method from my main projects Scraper class and just removed all the case statements in the try/catch to check for Connection/Timeout/404/Service/Server errors etc and put it into one simple Main method here...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://www.strictly-software.com"; // a site I own
    //int port = ????; // working in main project crawler
    int port = 3128; // from a list of working free proxies
    string proxyUser = "????"; // working in main project crawler
    string proxyPassword = "????"; // working in main project crawler
    string proxyIP = "167.99.230.151"; // from a list of working proxies

    ShowDebug("Make a request to: " + url + " with proxy:" + proxyIP + ":" + port.ToString());
    
    // user basic IP and Port proxy with no login
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP, port);

    /*
        // use default port, username and password to login
        // get same error with correct personal proxy and login but not
        // in main project
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyIP, port)
        {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUser, proxyPassword)
        };
    */

    ShowDebug("Use Proxy: " + proxy.Address.ToString());

    HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    client.Referer = "https://www.strictly-software.com";
    client.Method = "GET";
    client.ContentLength = 0;
    client.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";client.Proxy = proxy;
    client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0";
    client.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    client.KeepAlive = true;
    client.Timeout = 30;

    ShowDebug("make request with " + client.UserAgent.ToString());


    try
    {
        // tried adding this to see if it would help but didn't
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    
        // get the response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse();

        ShowDebug("response.ContentEncoding = " + response.ContentEncoding.ToString());
        ShowDebug("response.ContentType  = " + response.ContentType.ToString());

        ShowDebug("Status Desc: " + response.StatusDescription.ToString());
        ShowDebug("HTTP Status Code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());


        ShowDebug("Now get the full response back");

    //  old method not working with £ signs
        StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

        string ResponseContent = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();

        ShowDebug("content from response == " + Environment.NewLine + ResponseContent);

        ResponseStream.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    { 
    
        ShowDebug("An error occurred");
        ShowDebug("WebException " + ex.Message.ToString());         
        ShowDebug(ex.Status.ToString());

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ShowDebug("An error occurred");
        ShowDebug("Exception " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        ShowDebug("At the end");                
    }
}
```

The error messages from the console (ShowDebug is just a wrapper for the time + message)...

```
02/08/2020 00:00:00: Make a request to: https://www.strictly-software.com with proxy:167.99.230.151:3128
02/08/2020 00:00:00: Use Proxy: http://167.99.230.151:3128/
02/08/2020 00:00:00: make request with Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
02/08/2020 00:00:00: An error occurred
02/08/2020 00:00:00: WebException The operation has timed out
02/08/2020 00:00:00: Timeout
02/08/2020 00:00:00: At the end
```

I am sure it is just a something I have missed but I know that this code was copied from my main project that is currently crawling through 100s of pages with the same code and using a proxy with my credentials that work as I am getting data back at the moment from the main projects code.

I can ping the IP address of the proxy, but going to it in a browser returns a connection error, this is despite my big project using the same proxy to ripple through tons of pages and return HTML all night long...

I just wanted to update my main project by adding new methods to pass in custom proxies, or not use a proxy for the 1st attempt but if it fails then use one for a final attempt, or use a default proxy:port etc.

Comment: Did you check if your browser is using proxy extensions or something? Chrome can be such a pain with all those VPN apps.

Answer (score 1):

You set your timeout to be 30 milliseconds: `client.Timeout = 30;`

That could be causing your timeouts.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Nope, it didn't wait more than 5 seconds and I tried (30,60 and the 15 my working project that is rippling through hundreds of pages okay - uses as well) - with the errors WebException The operation has timed out; Whilst trying to access
strictly-software.com
ERROR = Timeout Error; The operation has timed out
That's with a proxy and without going through a proxy it doesn't wait at all before coming back with the same Timeout error. Just odd that proxy is being used right now in my main project with no errors at all.

Comment: @MonkeyMagix -- did you try changing `30` to `30000`? Sorry if that's a dumb question. I just want to make sure that you aren't typing 30,60 without converting to milliseconds first.

Comment: Yes you got it right 2nd time it was the WebClient.Timeout Property being too small both proxy and non proxy work with that test code posted now. I knew I was being a numbskull, I copied the class main method that works rippling through hundreds of pages a night and the default is only 15, however when I look at the methods being called there is one where I pass in the timeout value which is set to 30000 and overrides it, so when I just used the code from the class I used the default value which was obviously too small DOH! Staying up too late to code sometimes is not a good thing.

Comment: @MonkeyMagix -- well, that's a bummer. My dreams of winning the bounty have been crushed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but:
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netcore-3.1) for HttpWebRequest states the following:

> The local computer or application config file may specify that a
> default proxy be used. If the Proxy property is specified, then the
> proxy settings from the Proxy property override the local computer or
> application config file and the HttpWebRequest instance will use the
> proxy settings specified. If no proxy is specified in a config file
> and the Proxy property is unspecified, the HttpWebRequest class uses
> the proxy settings inherited from Internet Explorer on the local
> computer. If there are no proxy settings in Internet Explorer, the
> request is sent directly to the server.

Maybe there is a proxy in the IE settings configured? This does not explain why the request fails using the custom proxy, but it may be worth a shot.

I also suggest, that you test the free proxy using something like postman. From my experience, these free proxies don't work at least half of the time.

My best guess is, that when not using the proxy, the request fails because of the IE stuff and when using the proxy, the proxy itself is simply not working.

Hopefully this solves the problem...

Comment: No, I am definitely using the proxy and not the default IE proxy settings. A couple of the proxy IPs didn't work - prob blocked by the site which is why I was getting server denied request errors when I looked into the exception trace etc. Without using a proxy I can get to my own site okay now, but I need to turn on the ability to store cookies and keep them for the other site which my code is rippling through 100s of pages right now. They must have some sort of cookie/Session detection to stop crawlers. It is all working fine now.